# Suppose $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff show that $f$ is a closed map

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, compactness, closed-map

I have seen a few other proofs about this. I have written my own, and I just want to verify the error in my own logic.

The question states: Show that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous, where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is closed map (that is, $f$ caries closed sets to closed set).

Let $U$ be a closed set in $X.$ This implies that $U$ is compact since a closed subspace of a compact space is compact (Theorem 26.2 in Munkres). Since the image of a compact space is compact under a continuous map (by Theorem 26.5) we have that $f(U)$ is compact. Since every compact subspace of a Hausdorff space is closed (Theorem 26.3) this implies that $f(U)$ is closed. Therefore $f$ is a closed map.

I believe that the error comes from the idea that we don't know about other closed sets in $Y$. That my proof does not account for ALL closed sets in $Y$. Is this true?

Comment: Why do you have to know about other closed sets in $Y$? A closed map carries closed sets to closed sets which you demonstrated.

Comment: When I looked at other proofs to verify what I did, they started with closed sets in $Y$. So I was wondering if there was a reason that they did that, as opposed to starting with closed sets in $X$.

Comment: Do you have a reference? You leveraged two other theorems in your proof. Is it possible that the other proofs filled in those details and the details involved $Y$?

Comment: Your proof is correct and there is no mistake (except minor typo).

Comment: @JohnDouma yes it appears that they were proving some of the theorems that I used. I just skimmed the proof and saw that they were using closed sets in $Y$ and was confused why that would be necessary, and wondered if I needed to do more with the closed sets in $Y$.

Comment: Except for the typo where you swap $A$ for $U$ halfway through the proof, your proof looks correct.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ya I was copying the theorems from the book where they use $A$, because I realized some people might not have access to the book, and so my proof wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Other random proofs on the internet *could* be wrong, you know…. Look for one in a published and respected book e.g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no error in your proof. You do not need to know **all** closed subsets of $Y$, it suffices to know that compact subsets are closed.

By the way, your proof is the *standard proof*. I guess you found this proof as a solution to Munkres' exercise 6 in §26.